# Class OpportunityBatch must implement the method: System.Iterable<Opportunity> Database.Batchable<Opportunity>.start(Database.BatchableContext)

Tags: apex

I got error on below code please help me

```
global class OpportunityBatch implements Database.Batchable<Opportunity> {
    string Query;
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext Bc){
         Query =[select id,name from opportunity where stage = 'closed own'];
        return database.getQueryLocator (Query);

    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext Bc, List<Opportunity> scope){
        for(Opportunity op : Scope){
            database.delete(op,false);
            }

    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext Bc){

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have some problems with code compiling.

- Query should be enclosed with single-quote, as it is string, without "[" and "]" at the beginning and end of string, I moved query directly to Database.getQueryLocator method, as it could show error while compiling code .
- Interface `Database.Batchable` should be typed `Database.Batchable<SObject>`

The following code is compiling

```
global class OpportunityBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext Bc){
        return Database.getQueryLocator([select id from Opportunity where StageName = 'closed own']);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext Bc, List<Opportunity> scope){
        Database.delete(scope,false);
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext Bc){

    }
}
```

Do you need to do delete in execute method in loop ?

```
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext Bc, List<Opportunity> scope){
        Database.delete(scope,false);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander ... It is working fine  why we need to write query inside querylocator

Comment: Database.getQueryLocator method is overloaded method. It can accept String, or List<SObject> as parameter. If you pass String of query, you can do typos, and while compiling code you will note see any errors. If you pass List<Sobject> ([select id from Opportunity] = List<Sobject>), you will see compiling errors, if any exist in your query